# How to connect a button to a function in xpce/prolog

Tags: user-interface, swi-prolog, xpce

This is a button:

```
new(B,button(solve, message(@prolog, solve))),
    send(D,display,B),
    send(D, open),
```

This is a function:

```
solve(D, Row, Column) :-
    assert(path([[0, 0], [-1, 0]])),
    track(Row, Column),
    path(P),
    show_track(D,P).
```

How should I do?

Comment: What GUI library/toolkit are you using (I didn't know that there was a standardized Prolog GUI library)?

Comment: I don't know much about xpce/prolog, but I found the user guide online: http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/xpce/UserGuide/Contents.html (just in case you hadn't seen it - sorry I don't know if it answers your question)

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a sample to get you started:

```
:- use_module(library(pce)).

test:-
    new(D, dialog),
    new(W,  window('Test', size(100, 100))),
    send(D, append, new(B,button(solve, message(@prolog, solve, D, 10, 20)))),
    send(D, below, W),
    send(D, open),
    !.

solve(D, Row, Column) :-
  writeln(solve(D, Row, Column)).
```

Basically you have to add the arguments to the message, in this case I used D for the dialog and the constants 10 and 20 for Row and Column, and just print them to console in the `solve/3` procedure.